# Rails Parsing YAML file - each method with a filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I have a following YAML file:

```
---
main-menu:
  - item: Test1
    param: value
  - item: Test2
    param: value
  - notitem: Test3
    param: value
```

I'm trying to parse all `item` entries like so:

```
#Load menu file
menu = YAML.load_file(file)

#Recursive parse function
parse = lambda do |node|
  node.each do |item|
    if !item['item'].nil? then
     .. do something with item ..
    end #end if
  end #end each
end #end parse

#Return the main menu
parse.call(menu['main-menu'])
```

Which works just fine... Is there an easier way to filter out all entries that aren't an `item` using `node.each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I can see. `node` is an `Array` of `Hash` objects, so each needs to be conditionally checked before you can `.. do something with item ..`. You could just clean up the `node.each` slightly with a `next`

```
menu = YAML.load_file(file)

parse = lambda do |node|
  node.each do |item|
    next unless item.include?('item')
    # .. do something with item ..
  end
end

parse.call(menu['main-menu'])
```

You could alternatively call [`reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject) with a block

```
menu = YAML.load_file(file)

parse = lambda do |node|
  node.reject { |n| !n.include?('item') }.each do |item|
    # .. do something with item ..
  end
end

parse.call(menu['main-menu'])
```

Though I don't know that this is really "easier"!

Comment: It might not be 'easier' but IMO it looks a lot nicer :) Thanks!